# Restart skaction sequence

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

in my game, I have a skaction sequence where i use waitForDuration first, and do something else after. The problem is that when the user loses, I need the sequence to restart from the beginning, with waitForDuration. Does anyone know of a way to reset the sequence inside didMoveToView?

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        var wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(15)
        let secondAction = SKAction.sequence([wait, SKAction.runBlock({() in self.addSecond(0.8)})])
        self.runAction(secondAction, completion: {println("second done")})
}

 func addSecond(waitDuration: NSTimeInterval) {

        var move = SKAction.runBlock({() in self.createTargets()})
        var wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(waitDuration)
        var moveAndWait = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([move, wait]))
        self.runAction(moveAndWait, withKey: "movingAction2")   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove all action from the object by calling:

```
[object removeAllActions]
```

and then start the animation again.
Ideally, you can store the animation in a property and the run it when you need it instead pf regenerate it every time.

Comment: I've used self.removeAllActions when the game is lost, but when I restart the game the actions aren't brought back. I also tried to recall the actions when the user replays the game, but no luck.

Comment: my mistake, I made an error when recalling the action. It works, thanks!